# Adding non-nullable field to populated feature class

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-pro, file-geodatabase, esri-geodatabase

Having a populated feature class in a geodatabase, a non-nullable field should be added (or a currently nullable field changed to non-nullable).

That current field has currently no null values so I thought it's a straight forward job. With SQL I would use something like:

```
ALTER TABLE FeatureClassX
        ADD Status INTEGER NOT NULL.
    DEFAULT 0
```

However, I can not change the properties (non-null) with ArcGIS Pro 2.3.x nor with ArcGIS for Desktop 10.x. Also, using the `Add Field` and `Alter Field` tools do not allow me to change this property. Most likely due to the lack of being able to set/config a default value in those tools.

The only workaround I can come up at this point is to create a new feature class with same fields and properties and then copy each record one by one from the original feature class to the new one.

It is not difficult to write a script to do the workaround but I would like to avoid it and hope that I just have missed something in ArcGIS Pro 2.3.x and/or ArcGIS for Desktop 10.x. I am looking for a built-in solution for either of the ESRI products (or using Python) since I am currently lucky to have both installed.

---

Edit 2019-07-17 0821: `Alter Field` tool added to non-working solutions after I have tried umbe1987's answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a solution: 
[Error: Failed to add one of the specified fields. The field is not nullable](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000010006)

Works with ArcGIS for Desktop and ArcGIS Pro.

---

**Summary**

1. Create a New Feature Class

   - on the last wizard screen, import field properties from existing table
   - then change `Allow NULL values` to `yes` and set a default value for the desired field
2. Use Simple Data Loader to load data (or `Append` tool in ArcGIS Pro) from the old feature class

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE - UNFORTUNATELY THIS DOES NOT WORK IF THE FEATURE CLASS IS NOT EMPTY**

I guess you can try the [`Alter Field`](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/alter-field-properties.htm) geoprocessing tool.
It has a parameter `field_is_nullable` which you can set to `NON_NULLABLE`.
This should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you. Yeah I have seen that but "this option is only applicable if the input table is empty"

Comment: You're totally right, I thought the same but I did not find it in the help. Now I can see it...